# MongoDB : add New Field to existing sub document after $look stage or merge lookup response to main document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want new field "isActive" inside modifierStatus sub document which is coming from **modifieritems** collection.

**modifieritems** collection :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a5a0e6d40624b12453a67"),
    "modifierName" : "xxx",
    "isActive" : 1
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a5a0e6d40624b12453a6a"),
    "modifierName" : "yyy",
    "isActive" : 0
}
```

**favoritedrinks** collection :

```
{
  "alcoholName" : "whiskey",
  "modifierList" : [{
       "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a5a0e6d40624b12453a61"), 
       "modifierId" : ObjectId("5e6a5a0e6d40624b12453a67"),
       "modifierName" : "xxx",
     }
     {
       "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a5a0e6d40624b12453a66"),
       "modifierId" : ObjectId("5e6a5a0e6d40624b12453a6a"),
       "modifierName" : "yyy",
     }]
 }
```

my query is :

```
db.getCollection('favoritedrinks').aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "alcoholName": 1 } },
  {"$lookup": {
      "from": "modifieritems",
      localField: 'modifierList.modifierId', 
      foreignField: '_id', 
      as: 'modifier'
  }},
  {
     $project:{
        "alcoholName" : "$alcoholName",
        "modifierStatus":"$modifier", 
     }
   },
 ]);
```

But my expected result :

```
{
     "alcoholName" : "Whiskey",
      "modifierStatus" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a5a0e6d40624b12453a61"),
            "modifierId" : ObjectId("5e6a5a0e6d40624b12453a67"), 
            "modifierName" : "xxx",
            "isActive" : 1,
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a5a0e6d40624b12453a66"),
            "modifierId" : ObjectId("5e6a5a0e6d40624b12453a6a"),
            "modifierName" : "yyy",
            "isActive" : 0,
        }
    ]
}
```

anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query :

Update with new requirement :

```
db.favoritedrinks.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "alcoholName": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "modifieritems",
      localField: "modifierList.modifierId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "modifierStatus"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      modifierStatus: {
        $map: {
          input: "$modifierList",
          as: "m",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [ /** As filter would only get one object (cause you'll have only one matching doc in modifieritems coll for each "modifierList.modifierId", So getting first element out of array, else you need to take this array into an object & merge that field to particular object of 'modifierList') */ 
                  {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$modifierStatus",
                      cond: {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$this._id",
                          "$$m.modifierId"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              },
              "$$m"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      modifierStatus: 1,
      alcoholName: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EIE0vZhLL9S)

**Old :**

```
db.favoritedrinks.aggregate([
    {
        "$sort": {
            "alcoholName": 1
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "modifieritems",
            let: {
                id: "$modifierList.modifierId"
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$id"] } }
                },
                /** Adding a new field modifierId(taken from _id field of modifieritems doc) 
                 * to each matched document from modifieritems coll */
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        modifierId: "$_id"
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "modifierStatus"
        }
    },
    /** By mentioning 0 to particular fields to remove them & retain rest all other fields */
    {
        $project: {
            modifierList: 0,
            _id: 0
        }
    }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cffWesz_hCx)

Comment: i have modify my collection.could u your please check..actuallyi want to get favoritedrinks.modifierList._id value in my expcted result

Answer (score 0):

When you want `$project` to include a field's current value while keeping the same field name, you need only specify `:1`.  When you use `"$field"` you are explicitly setting the value, which will overwrite any existing value.

Try making your projection:

```
{
     $project:{
        "alcoholName" : 1,
        "modifier.isActive": 1,
        "modifier.modifierName": 1 
     }
}
```

Comment: like how?if this is my query  db.getCollection('favoritedrinks').aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "alcoholName": 1 } },
  {"$lookup": {
      "from": "modifieritems",
      localField: 'modifierList.modifierId', 
      foreignField: '_id', 
      as: 'modifier'
  }},
  {
     $project:{
        "alcoholName" : "$alcoholName",
        "modifierStatus":"$modifier", 
     }
   },
 ]);

Comment: Use this $project stage instead of the one you are using.